# How to replace the url in window.open with jquery depending on the country ip

Tags: javascript, jquery

I ve got a problem here and I need some help. I am using a chat service called my website chat. I have setup a second account for america and all I want is to replace the `onclick` url of the chat with the american one depending on the IP address. I am using a script from "Maxmind" to detect the ip I haven't yet found a way to to replace the url in there.

So the code I ve got is :

```
<img src="http://static.ssl7.net/b/en/c3c88152ba6c7e56746dc864606b/1.gif" style="cursor:     pointer; border: none;" alt="Helpdesk Software" onclick="window.open('http://ssl7.net/chat/en/c3c88152ba6c7e56746dc864606b/'+document.location.href,'','height=400,width=300,menubar=no, location=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=no,status=yes');">
```

and I need to turn it into this

```
<img src="http://static.ssl7.net/b/en/b5695d38e0f3db83ebf705147155/8.gif" style="position:fixed;top:170px;right:0;z-index:9999;cursor:pointer;border:none;" alt="Live Support Chat" onclick="window.open('http://ssl7.net/chat/en/b5695d38e0f3db83ebf705147155/'+document.location.href,'','height=400,width=300,menubar=no, location=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=no,status=yes');">
```

So basically the only thing that is changing is the url.
I am trying to replace it using jquery but I cant make it work and please not that the `phone[country]` detects the ip.

```
j('img').each(function() {
  var href = $(this).attr('onclick');
  j(this).click(function() { window.open = 'http://ssl7.net/chat/en/b5695d38e0f3db83ebf705147155/mecmesin.com'; })
         .removeAttr('onclick' , phone[country]);
}, );
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your kind replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i catch the two image-elements of ssl7 with jQuery. after this i go through each of them and replace the onclick-Attr with RegEx.

Hope this helps. Have a nice day.

```
var newCode = 'b5695d38e0f3db83ebf705147155';
jQuery('img[onclick]').each(function() {
   var sOnClick = jQuery(this).attr('onclick');
   jQuery(this).attr('onclick', sOnClick.replace(/\/(.{28})\//, '/'+newCode+'/'));
});
```

Comment: Omg I need to get into RegEx a bit more ... Thanks a lot buddy